# ORA-00907 while creating a table in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE passager
(
codePassager    NUMBER(38,0)    CONSTRAINT  passager_code_pk        PRIMARY KEY,
nom             VARCHAR2(15)    CONSTRAINT  passager_nom_nn         NOT NULL,
prenom          VARCHAR2(15)    CONSTRAINT  passager_prenom_nn      NOT NULL,
adresse         VARCHAR2(50)    CONSTRAINT  passager_adresse        NOT NULL,
telephone       VARCHAR2(10)    CONSTRAINT  passager_tel            NOT NULL,
ville           VARCHAR2(20)    CONSTRAINT  passager_ville          NOT NULL,
pays            VARCHAR2(20)    CONSTRAINT  passager_pays           NOT NULL, 
status          VARCHAR2(1)     CONSTRAINT  passager_status         NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE reservation
(
codePassager    NUMBER(38,0)    CONSTRAINT  passager_reservation_codePsg REFERENCES passager(codePassager),
codeReservation NUMBER(38,0)    CONSTRAINT  reservation_pk          PRIMARY KEY (codePassager, codeReservation), 
statusReservation VARCHAR2(1)   CONSTRAINT  reservation_status      NOT NULL,
dateReservation   VARCHAR2(8)   CONSTRAINT  reservation_date        NOT NULL
);
```

Oracle tells me I have an error:

> ORA-00907 on line "codeReservation NUMBER(38,0)   CONSTRAINT 
>   reservation_pk            PRIMARY KEY (codePassager, codeReservation),"

I spend 2 hours searching for an answer and still don't understand what is the problem. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary key constraint isn't on a single column, it needs to be created separately not as part of the column definition.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation
(
  codePassager    NUMBER(38,0)    CONSTRAINT  passager_reservation_codePsg REFERENCES passager(codePassager),
  codeReservation NUMBER(38,0)    , 
  statusReservation VARCHAR2(1)   CONSTRAINT  reservation_status      NOT NULL,
  dateReservation   VARCHAR2(8)   CONSTRAINT  reservation_date        NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT  reservation_pk      PRIMARY KEY (codePassager, codeReservation)
);
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate this. May the force, love and prosperity be always with you.